# OptaPlanner, set the other shadow variable in the VariableListener

Tags: optaplanner

In the example taskassignment (and also in other examples), in the VariableListener(), only the shadow variable of the passed in PlanningEntity object is being updated. Like in

```
@Override
public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector<TaskAssigningSolution> scoreDirector, Task task) {
    updateStartTime(scoreDirector, task);
}
```

the shadow variable of the argument task object is updated. I think a solution object will be kept updating until all its PlanningEntity/PlanningVariable are filled. And whenever a PlanningVariable is changed afterVariableChanged() will be called, and then the rule will be calculated to update the score. My question is, will there be any problem if I update another entity's shadow variable in the afterVariableChanged()? Not only the shadow variable of the passed in object. I can get the other entity by calling scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One shadow variable can update another shadow variable.

For example, when an instance shadow variable C (sourced on A) changes, it might also change 1 or more instances of shadow variable E (sourced on C and B):

[image]

Do call the before/after methods as needed.