# OptaPlanner, update multiple CustomShadowVariables in VariableListener

Tags: optaplanner

This question is to clarify [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68943872/optaplanner-set-the-other-shadow-variable-in-the-variablelistener) from me. optaplanner-bom 7.45.0.Final. My case: the *PlanningEntity* is Task, it contains *PlanningVariable* startingTimeGrain and *CustomShadowVariable* duration. Yes the duration depends on the starting time. In the *VariableListener()*, two arguments passed in, one is the *PlanningSolution* object call it "s", the other is the *Task* object call it "task". Question, in the listener method, because all Task objects can be accessed through the "s", after changing the "task"s "duration", will there be any problem to change other task's "duration". For example, totally two tasks: taskA and taskB, in the listener method, when object taskA is passed in, may I also change the duration of the taskB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may.

One `VariableListener` may affect the shadow variable (on which it is annotated) for **multiple** instances of the class that holds that shadow variable.

For example, in the case below, the arrival time listener gets 1 change (amsterdam being added), but affects 3 entity instances:

[image]